# Prolog. If Prolog found first solution then it stops finding

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

Task is: Determine what numbers a,b,c is divider of N. For example: (a=2,b=3,c=4,n=2 Answer is a,c).

So, I wrote following code:

```
PREDICATES
    a(integer,integer)
    m(integer,integer,integer,integer)
CLAUSES
    a(X,N):-
        0 = X mod N,
        write(X).

    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(A,N).
    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(B,N).
    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(C,N).
GOAL
    m(2,3,4,2).
```

but if Prolog found first solution (in my case a=2) then it stops and displays it. But, in my case answer will be a=2, c=4.
My question is "how Prolog can check all predicates"?

Comment: It looks to me like it should yield two solutions. I don't have Turbo Prolog, but I tried the predicates in GNU Prolog (after converting the `=` to the ISO compliant `=:= operator) and it just worked. Some peculiarity with Turbo Prolog, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is a peculiarity of Visual Prolog. I solve my problem using `fail` predicate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog begins backtracking when a call fails. In certain situations, it may be necessary to initialize the performance of backtracking to find other solutions. Prolog has a special predicate `fail`, which calls unsuccessful finish, and, therefore, initializes refund.

So, I rewrote my code:

```
PREDICATES
    a(integer,integer)
    m(integer,integer,integer,integer)
CLAUSES
    a(X,N):-
        0 = X mod N,
        write(X),nl.

    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(A,N),fail.
    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(B,N),fail.
    m(A,B,C,N):-
        a(C,N).
GOAL
    m(2,3,4,2).
```

Comment: It's sort of an illusion that this works because you write out the value of `X` whether the `m` predicate succeeds or fails. Evidently, in Turbo Prolog, it doesn't seem to backtrack after success of a GOAL, which is very odd.